# Link extraction using owasp-java-html-sanitizer

Tags: java, owasp, html-sanitizing

I'm planning on using the owasp-java-html-sanitizer to perform a few tasks on user generated html.

I'd like to extract a list of the URLs from the html string.

I would also like to make sure all links have the target set to "_blank", this seems to be similar to the `HtmlPolicyBuilder.requireRelNofollowOnLinks` configuration. (done)

---

```
PolicyFactory linkRewrite = new HtmlPolicyBuilder().allowAttributes("href").onElements("a")
      .requireRelNofollowOnLinks().allowElements(new ElementPolicy() {
        public String apply(String elementName, List<String> attrs) {
          attrs.add("target");
          attrs.add("_blank");
          return "a";
        }
      }, "a").toFactory();
```

This adds `target="_blank"` to links, not sure its the best way to accomplish it.

This also extracts the URLs:

```
.allowElements(new ElementPolicy() {
        public String apply(String elementName, List<String> attrs) {
          for (int i = 0, n = attrs.size(); i < n; i += 2) {
            if ("href".equals(attrs.get(i))) {
              urls.add(attrs.get(i + 1));
              break;
            }
          }
          attrs.add("target");
          attrs.add("_blank");
          return elementName;
        }
      }, "a")
```

Comment: You can use an attribute policy so that you don't need to do `"href".equals(...)` or loop over the contents of the `attrs` array.  Are you allowing `target` elsewhere?  If so, you might end up with two targets which might not be what you want.

Comment: What is your question, btw?

Comment: It's been awhile but I think the question is before the `hr` and everything is what I've figured out since asking the question. If you flesh out an answer using the `attribute policy` I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.allowElements(
   new ElementPolicy() {
     public String apply(String elementName, List<String> attrs) {
       // Make sure that all links open in new windows/tabs without
       // using <base target> which also affects unsanitized links.
       attrs.add("target");
       attrs.add("_blank");
       return elementName;
     }
   }, "a")
.allowAttributes("href").matching(
   new AttributePolicy() {
     public String apply(String elementName, String attributeName, String value) {
       // Collect all link URLs.
       urls.add(value);
       return value;
     }
   }).onElements("a")
```